# How to remove or hide SVG using jQuery or other JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to create a SVG and set 'double click' to remove or hide it. With this code double click hide the canvas and all other SVG together. I am new to programming, there must be something wrong with my code.

```
 var draw = SVG('output').size(1000, 500);     
      var table = draw.circle(150)
        .fill('red')
        .stroke('black')
        .center(150, 300);

        $("svg").on('dblclick',function(event){
           $(this).hide(); 
        }
        });
```

I wish to remove or hide the svg 'table' when I double click it.

hide the canvas and all other SVG together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class to the svg `table` so you can hide it by `class query selector`  using `table.attr("class", "table");`

See code snippet :

```js
var draw = SVG('output').size(1000, 500);     
      var table = draw.circle(150)
        .fill('red')
        .stroke('black')
        .center(150, 300);
        //add class to table svg
        table.attr("class", "table");

        $("svg").on('dblclick',function(event){
           $(".table").hide(); //hide the table svg by selecting his class
        
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.3/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: The green check ✅？？Yes I did it. Thank you!